# Is there any story with anthropomorphised animals that tries to be somewhat plausible?

Tags: animals

I am looking for interesting books or short stories that try to give a reasonable explanation for the existence of talking, gun-shooting, vehicle-driving animals.
Something like uplift, or convergent evolution, or selective breeding.
If not, a simple, fun, action-packed adventure would do.

Comment: Why the votes to close without explanation? I feel I've provided a good answer to this. It may fall under opinion-based, but at least let the person know why you're voting to close. That way the have a chance to right whatever perceived wrongs they've committed. Let them address your concerns with an edit. So many hit-n-runs...

Comment: One of the topics that is considered explicitly off-topic on this site is requests for recommendations of selected books or stories. This is because this kind of question almost always generates subjective opinion-based answers that can't properly be seen as right or wrong, and there can never be a *right* answer, and so it's not a good fit for the site. You can see more details on the [about] page.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. You needn't gone to so much exposition. I only asked about the downvoters. And why they didn't comment about their downvoting. My point was **tell the person asking the question why they are being downvoted.** It's rather simple. Don't just VTC. Leave a reason the OP can learn from. Help newer members, don't be holier-than-thou.

Comment: Yes, I am inexeperienced here and @MeatTrademark is right, downvoting without explanation is not only unproductive, it's just rude. I understood that questions that were too broad were not good, but I thought my question is highly specific. I bet there are only a handful of actual correct answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphic novel [WE3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We3) by writer Grant Morrison and artist Frank Quitely is pretty interesting and plausible and rather close to what you are asking.

> The story follows the journey of We3, a squad of three prototype "animal weapons," as they flee captivity. The group consists of a dog, "Bandit" a.k.a. "1"; a cat, "Tinker" a.k.a. "2"; and a rabbit, "Pirate" a.k.a. "3", who were all kidnapped from a nearby city and encased in robotic armor. They were also given a limited ability to speak through skull implants. Their body armor fields numerous weapons, including mine laying devices, machine guns and razor claws.

As personal opinion goes, I loved it. It feels real and terrible and sad and works as a commentary on control and abuse of power. Highly recommended.

The GN consists of a three-issue miniseries, and all three covers were great, but cover number one really got to me. The right combination of illustration and photo-realism that is hard to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Sounds great. I will definitely look into it. Thanks